# How do I add a submenu for all “Advanced Options for ...” in GRUB menu?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04

Near every OS that I've installed has an ***"Advanced boot option"*** submenu created by Grub. Now what I want to achieve is to *"group"* every of those submenus in one submenu that I will call ***"Other"***. By my research, it seems like I have to modify the /etc/grub.d/10_linux file but I don't really know how without breaking grub

Edit :

I forgot to mention that I need to add a —class in order to have an icon sitting next to the “other” submenu that I need to create.. as André pointed out in the comments, I could have used grub-customizer if I wanted to create a submenu without an icon which is totally the way to go to achieve that. But here it’s an other story...

Answer (score 0):

you can use grub-customizer GUI tool to create submenus.
With grub customizer opened right-click in one of "Advanced boot option" and select "Create submenu". To move the others to that submenu, right-click in other submenus and select "Move Up".

To get grub-customizer in Ubuntu (19.10 or later) you must do:

```
sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

If you are 19.04 or older you must add [PPA first](https://launchpad.net/%7Edanielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer).

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot to add that I NEED to add a —class option in order to have an icon next to the “other” folder that I want to create... and as far as I know, grub-customizer doesn’t support adding option for a submenu... I’m really sorry about that